# Ejecutar esta consulta desde .Bat

Tags: batch

Hola quisiera me ayudarn Gracias, tengo la siguiente consulta:

```
CREATE DATABASE almacen;
```

la cual quiero ejecutar mediante un Bat, pense en algo como esto:

```
@echo off
echo --test >crear.sql
echo CREATE DATABASE almacen1;>>crear.sql
C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysql.exe -h localhost -u root -ptresa456 < "crear.sql"
```

pero no me corre, ¿como la puedo ejecutar desde batch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba pasar el SQL en la misma línea, asi te evitas que el mysql.exe no encuentre el archivo

```
C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysql.exe -h localhost -u root -ptresa456 -e "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS almacen1;"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysql.exe -h localhost -u root -ptresa456 -e "create database almacen1"
```

Comment: Podrias explicar un poco tu respuesta, ya que fue reportada como de baja calidad.